# unable to print the Pass/Fail in the email body

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, cypress

Is there a way to print the Test case Pass/Fail in the body of the email while running the Cypress test from Jenkins Pipeline like reading the json file ?

@sample

- ```
   def myObj = jsonParser(response.content)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try use linux `tee` cmd to write Cypress test output standard output(Jenkins build console) and a file, then you read the file for mail body.

```
pipeline {
  
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          < Cypress test cmd> | tee test.output
        '''
      }
    }

    stage('Send mail') {
      steps {
        script {
          def test_result = readFile 'test.output'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```